# BDE Borland link with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, bde

I have an old software created in Delphi (not my) with paradox database on local pc.
It is very good software and I have license for it.
What I want is to "link" or "sync" or totally "replace" that database with SQL Server database so I can share it, use triggers etc, and use same database from multiple PCs.

I have BDE with SQL links but how to do setup? Is that for purpose I need? Any other idea?

Comment: "SQL server",  as in MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. I would like to use MS SQL server.

Comment: You have the code for this application? Or do you just have the executable and related runtime files? Delphi still exists and is supported - just migrate your code to a current version?

Comment: No, I do not have source code, it is not my app. Just exe and runtime files. Any way to upgrade it to MS SQL? There is PDOXUSRS.NET and other DB files.